# How can I clone git repo to specific path in Jenkins i.e. /var

Tags: git, jenkins

While cloning the repo to Jenkins my Jenkins node go offline due to space constraints in /home/jenkins folder. Hence I need to clone the repo to other path instead of default Jenkins path. Can anyone please let me know how can I clone to specific path in Jenkins.

Comment: How are you doing your clone in the first place?  My only experience is with pipelines, but Jenkins has a few ways to configure a checkout.

Comment: The better thing to do would be to remove the space constraint because it will only cause trouble down the line. If there is no way around it you can just wrap everything in a dir("/var"){ ...} block and do a manual checkout (git url: "...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using git plugin, that should give you the option to mention checkout directory for git clone.
In Source code management section, under additional behaviours, there should be a option 'check out to a sub-directory' ( location might change depend on the plugin version). Setting this value  will make the plugin to check out the repository into the folder relative to your workspace.

If you are looking to change your workspace also,you can set custom workspace.

For free style jobs,you should be able to set that from configuration UI. If you check advanced project option, there is a option for 'use custom workspace' and set the value. Or else you can check advanced option in build section and check if 'use custom workspace' option is there or not.

For pipeline jobs, you can try the ws instruction to set custom workspace. ws("C:\jenkins") { echo "jenkins workspace" }